# 8086 Program print your name as array of hex values of ascii using loop

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, x86-64

Here is my code, but when I use my debugger I get an error once I reach the int21 h command which says:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF6E9B01034 in MP2_KyleRuiter.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.
```

Program:

```
ExitProcess PROTO

.data 

string DB 4bh, 79h, 6ch, 65h, 20h, 52h, 75h, 69h, 74h, 65h, 72h, 00h ; My Name

COUNT = ($-string) ; string length calculation

.code

main proc

 mov rcx,COUNT ; loop counter

 mov rsi,offset string 

 L1:

 mov dl,[rsi] ;gets character from the array

  mov ah,2 ;displays character

 inc rsi; points to next character

 Loop L1 ;decrements rcx until 0

 mov rax, 4c00h

 int 21h ; displays

RET
main ENDP

END
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  You've got 64 bit assembly language mixed with a **16 bit DOS** system call.

Comment: yes this is 64bit assembly, so what are the commands that I may use instead of the 16-bit dos interruptions?

Answer (score 3):

`int 21h` & co. is 16-bit MS-DOS stuff, while the rest of the code you wrote is x86 64bit assembly. On 64-bit Windows you are invoking god-knows-what interrupt handler, which results in a crash.

If you want to print stuff when running under 64 bit Windows you have to invoke the relevant syscalls (`GetStdHandle` to get a handle to the console, `WriteFile` to write the data); MASM makes this relatively simple through the `INVOKE` directive.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use DOS interrupts, like `int 21h`, in a 64-bit Windows executable. Modern Windows isn't a DOS-based system, so it doesn't use that interface anymore.

If you want to write a DOS executable, you'll need to use 16-bit instructions, and run it in an emulator (like [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/)).

If you want to write a 64-bit Windows executable, you'll need to use Windows library calls.

Pick one.

Comment: `int 21h` is a DOS interrupt, not a BIOS interrupt. `int 21h` doesn't work in a bare metal environment on standard x86 hardware.

Answer (score 0):

int 21h with AH set to 4Ch says to terminate with a return code.  It looks like your debugger does not know how to step over/into a terminate.  That makes some sense, I suppose.

**Belay my last.  I stand corrected.**

You might find this helpful, though:
[Why does using "int 21h" on Assembly x86 MASM cause my program to crash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22512471/why-does-using-int-21h-on-assembly-x86-masm-cause-my-program-to-crash)

Comment: `int 21h` & co. is 16-bit MS-DOS stuff, while he is writing x86 64bit assembly. On 64-bit Windows (or whatever OS he is running this stuff on) he is invoking god-knows-what interrupt handler, which results in a crash.

Comment: Did the meaning change?  MS does try so hard for backward compatibility.

Comment: Yes. It doesn't have any meaning in Windows executables.

Comment: So what does 21h mean now?

Comment: Nothing. It's an illegal operation, and will crash your program.

Comment: "Crash the application", apparently. Seriously, the only interrupt which was vaguely still supported in 32-bit Windows-NT-derived OSes AFAIK was 2Eh (it is the mechanism used internally to perform the syscalls), I don't know if it's still in use under 64 bit Windows.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Whether they're still using an interrupt or if they've moved to `syscall`, it's not a documented, supported, or recommended way of interacting with the OS anymore.

Comment: @duskwuff: of course, I was just digressing about what kind of interrupt handler may still be alive under Win64. The way to go is to call the relevant APIs through `ntdll`/`kernel32.dll` & co.