# How do I print what I want in MASM? What does mov ah, 2 before int 21h do?

Tags: windows, assembly, dos, masm

I want to print my characters and variables' values and strings on my DOS screen

and I've searched for lots of stuff and most of them told me to use 'int' instruction

```
    .code
    main PROC
        mov dl, 'a'
        mov ah, 2h
        int 21h 
        exit
    main ENDP
    end main
```

I've wrote a code like this, by coping from internets.

but I don't get what 'mov ah, 2h' is for and

**'int 21h' always triggers a memory error**

I need to know

- how to get an string, integer input by the user,
- how to print the values I want.

Comment: start here: http://www.phatcode.net/res/223/files/html/toc.html

Comment: What does `exit` mean? What is a memory error? Is it something returned after you execute your code, or is it returned by the assembler (compiler)? Anyway the `mov ah, 2h` is the subcommand to the interrupt service. Consider it as a huge switch case. All other parameters are put in zero or more registers. (Also here's a cheat sheet for the other services: http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html)

Comment: I meant exception thrown for memory error, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Your program won't work because that code generate a DOS executable and modern windows version don't support them anymore ([here for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22512471/why-does-using-int-21h-on-assembly-x86-masm-cause-my-program-to-crash)).

for what your code do, let's analize your code:

```
.code
    main PROC
        mov dl, 'a' ; Move character 'a' to the dl register
        mov ah, 2h  ; set the ah register to match with the 02 function code (write to STDOUT)
        int 21h ; trigger the 21h interrupt 
        exit
    main ENDP
    end main
```

if you want do read character in this way (that as I write before, is not anymore supported) read [here](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html), and look to the READ CHARACTER TO STDIN

EDIT: here a simple echo function:

```
; retrive a char from input
mov ah, 1h
int 21h 
;print that char back
mov dl, al
mov ah, 2h
int 21h
```

Comment: I see that this doesn't work anymore, and that the site you've linked is useful, but I don't know how to use that information :(
could you give me a simple sample for me to know how to use them?

Comment: you have to move to ah the function code (01), and then you have the readed character saved in al. see [here](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah01)

Comment: "modern windows", are you having me on? :D

Answer (score -2):

The simplest way to answer your question about what "mov ah,2" is for,
its just like using a "cout" statement in C++ , mov ah,2  where 2 represents a
 function call for printing a character on the screen and moving in ah and then "int 21h"
 causes your function (2) to be executed and whatever is in data register is to be printed.

MOV DL, 'A'
MOV AH, 2 
INT 21H

The code written above prints the single character 'A' on the screen.
Hope that Answered your question